# How do i know if the rotation lock is on or off?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I just need to know if there is a way to get the rotation lock status in windows phone 8, for example

```
if(rotationLock == ON)do stuff;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately There is **not any method or way** to know that **Rotation lock is On/Off.** but you can set **SupportedOrientations** and **Orientation** in **Xaml** or you can manage Orientation in **CS** as under:

```
protected override void OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
        base.OnOrientationChanged(e);
}
```